# How can I make WebApplicationContext access beans in ApplicationContext?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired, managed-bean, applicationcontext

This is how I try to bootstrap Spring in my Java Web Application:

```
public class SpringBootstrap implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        final AnnotationConfigApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootContextConfiguration.class);

        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.register(WebContextConfiguration.class);
        webContext.setParent(rootContext);

        final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webContext);
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("springDispatcher", dispatcherServlet);
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        final ContextLoaderListener contextLoadListener = new ContextLoaderListener(webContext);
        servletContext.addListener(contextLoadListener);
    }
}
```

And RootContextConfiguration and WebContextConfiguration classes are as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "biz.tugay.janeleven.root")
public class RootContextConfiguration {
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "biz.tugay.janeleven.web")
public class WebContextConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

When I try deploying the application to Tomcat and start I will get:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [biz.tugay.janeleven.root.service.AppUserService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I am also including the HelloServlet and AppUserService classes here, with their package information:

package biz.tugay.janeleven.root.service;

```
@Service
public class AppUserService {

    public AppUser addAppUser(String name) {
        final AppUser appUser = new AppUser(name);
        AppUserDB.addUser(appUser);
        return appUser;
    }

    public Collection<AppUser> getAllAppUsers() {
        return AppUserDB.getAll();
    }
}

package biz.tugay.janeleven.web;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class HelloWorldServlet {

    @Autowired
    private AppUserService appUserService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloWorld(Model model) {
        final Collection<AppUser> appUserList = appUserService.getAllAppUsers();
        model.addAttribute("appUserList", appUserList);
        return "hello.jsp";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addApplicationUser(@RequestParam("username") String username) {
        appUserService.addAppUser(username);
        return "redirect:/";
    }

}
```

My expectation is that, WebContextConfiguration should be able to find beans that are managed by RootContextConfiguration since I am calling:

```
webContext.setParent(rootContext);
```

during the bootstrap process. But obviously I am missing something.

Comment: HelloWorldServlet is absolutely not a servlet. It's a Spring MVC handler. Be careful with terminology in code or you keep confusing yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the web context will inherit from the root context, however
you did not include the rootContext when you initialized servletContext.addListener(); see similar code below which will help you fix your issue.

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.register(WebConfig.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
            new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "you did not include the rootContext"? Did not include where?

Comment: I mean to say that you must add the rootContext to:  servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(someContext)).  You 'accidentally' loaded the webContext, which makes the webContext the root context.  You intended to pass the rootContext to the ContextLoaderListener, and make webContext a child via the dispatcherServlet

Comment: I do not understand. Why do you need the servletContext.addListener... part for rootContext, but not for dispatcherContext? Also, can you please see http://www.tugay.biz/2016/01/a-spring-hello-world-example-with-only.html ? Here, in SpringWebAppInitializer no addListener(new ContextLoaderListener( but all goes fine?

Comment: Hi Koray.  I have looked for a good online explanation and found very respected Josh Long's blog which describes what I have done: http://joshlong.com/index.html.  Look for 'Simplified Web Configuration with Spring'.  Perhaps he explains it perfectly.  You can load all your beans into the dispatcher context perfectly fine (as you did in the example provider) however you requested (and rightly so - it is a better design) to separate service beans in the root context, and controller specific beans in the dispatcher context.  To get this separation you follow the pattern I (and Josh Long) shows.